# Imports statement throwing compile error after upgrade to .NET 6

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-core, migration

I've taken on the so far painful task of trying to port an old, semi-complex, proprietary library from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 (so basically making the jump from the old "Framework" to "Core"). I used the [.NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview) as a starter and have been trying to get the library to build ever since. After removing 80% of the files from the project in an attempt to find what will still compile, I've come across this strange case:

```
Imports TypeShortcut = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of MyNamespace.Test2)

Public Class Test
    Dim Thing As TypeShortcut
End Class

Public Class Test2

End Class
```

Obviously the above is a useless simplification from the actual production code. But I've added the above exactly into the project as a test. Currently, this code alone is what is preventing my DLL from compiling. If I comment out lines 1 and 4, the project compiles, and if I uncomment them, the compile fails with the error:

> error BC30002: Type 'MyNamespace.Test2' is not defined.

`MyNamespace` is the root namespace for the project.

I tried this same code in another upgraded project and it compiles just fine, so I don't know if you'll be able to reproduce this. (The other project compiles to an executable instead of a DLL. Not sure if that makes a difference.)

I've already tried:

- Closing and reopening Visual Studio
- Clean then Rebuild on the project
- Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders

What do you think could be wrong with the project that is preventing this from compiling like it should? What else can I try?

Comment: Is `MyNamespace` the root namespace for the project? Is all the code in the snippet you posted contained in the same code file?

Comment: I just created two new projects in the same solution - VB class libraries targeting .NET Framework 4.8.1 and .NET 6 named ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 respectively. I copied your code into the Class1.vb code file in each project and changed the namespace to `ClassLibrary1` and `ClassLibrary2` as required. Both projects built successfully. I used the latest version of VS 2022.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, `MyNamespace` is the root namespace for the project. And all the code posted above is in one file (with no other code in that file). I'm also using the latest version of VS 2022 (just updated last night).

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a .net 6 migration, because it also does not compile with the old .NET Framework.

Try adding the Namespace around your class definition or removing the namespace prefix on your first line. For example, this compiles for me:

```
Imports TypeShortcut = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of MyNamespace.Test2)

Namespace MyNamespace

    Public Class Test
        Dim Thing As TypeShortcut
    End Class

    Public Class Test2

    End Class
```

Comment: `MyNamespace` is the root for the project. So adding another `MyNamespace` in the file would make it `MyNamespace.MyNamespace.Test2`. I don't think it's a syntax issue in the code itself, since it does compile in my second project.

Comment: I agree, your code compiled for me too when I created a new VB Library project targeting .net 6 in Visual Studio 2022 and set the Root Namespace to MyNamespace.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around for a while, I eventually just decided to do things the "hard" way. I made a brand new .NET 6 project, manually copied over all the settings I could find, manually re-added all the needed references/dependencies/packages, and then manually copied all the code and resource files. And everything works.

I don't know what the Upgrade Assistant did to that project that screwed it up, but I no longer need to try and figure it out.

(I still have the messed up project for now, though. So if anyone comes up with an actual answer to the question as written, getting the Upgrade Assistant project to work properly, I'll still give proper credit.)